# How to import a variable from Background Script to a Content Script? [Chrome Extension]

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Right Now My Background Script Is:

```
   function idInfo() {
        var idPage = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/" +itemID+ ".json";
        $.getJSON(idPage, function(data) {
            idData = data.styles;
            console.log(idData);
            var colorInfo = idData.find(element => element.name == getItemColor);
            console.log(colorInfo);
            colorID = colorInfo.id;
            console.log("!!! COLOR ID FOUND\t" + colorID + "\t!!!")
            var sizesData = colorInfo.sizes;
            console.log(sizesData);
            var sizeInfo = sizesData.find(element => element.name == getItemSize);
            console.log(sizeInfo);
            sizeID = sizeInfo.id;
            console.log("!!! SIZE ID FOUND\t" + sizeID + "\t!!!")

            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {sizeID: sizeID}, function() {
                    console.log("Settings saved");
                });
            });

            addToCart();
        });
    }

    function addToCart() {
        var atcPage = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/mobile/" +itemID+ "/" +colorID;

        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: atcPage
        })
    }
```

And My Content Script Is (which is active when on the atcPage that you are directed to in the background script):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function({sizeID}) {
    function clickAdd() {
        document.querySelector('input[name="commit"]').click();
    }

    function select(id, value) {
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.value = value;
        clickAdd();
    }

    select("s", sizeID);
});
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong, I'm trying to import the sizeID variable from my background script to my content script, what should I do to do this? Right now I'm trying to do chrome.tabs.query on the background and chrome.runtime.onmessage on the content script but it's not working (guessing I'm doing something wrong)

```
{
    "name": "supreme",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.supremenewyork.com/"],
            "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js"]
        },
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/mobile/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "getToken.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts":
            [
                "content.js", "jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Popup",
        "default_icon": "suppic.png"
    },
    "permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "unlimitedStorage", "tabs", "notifications", "tabCapture", "https://*.supremenewyork.com/", "background", "activeTab", "<all_urls>" ]
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the parameter e.g. `addListener(function({sizeID}) {`

Comment: updated it to that, still doesnt work.

Comment: Did you reload the extension on  `chrome://extensions` page and the site tab too? Show your manifest.json just in case.

Comment: yea i did and i just posted the manifest

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0AWBA55q

thats a pastebin of my whole background script btw

Comment: Looks like you're sending the message before opening the tab. You need to wait until the tab has loaded and the content script is ready to receive messages. Might be easier to reverse the direction of communication (send a message from the content script and reply to it in the background script using a global variable) or simply put the value in chrome.storage.local which you can read in the content script directly.

Comment: if I save sizeID in the background script in chorme.storage.local, how do I use it in the content script?

Comment: tried to do localstorage and it didn't work, tried to set the sizeid in the background and get the size id in the content

Comment: Find an example of using chrome.storage.local and use it.

Comment: i did, it didnt work

Comment: The API is asynchronous so the data should be used inside the callback. Anyway can't help without seeing the *actual* code you are using.

Comment: I linked the pastebin in the comments

Comment: That code doesn't use chrome.storage.local.

Comment: i tried it, it  didn't work for me

Comment: And we're back to my previous comment. Can't help without seeing that code.

Comment: never mind, thanks i figured it out, i was using the wrong chrome storage lol